# How to run recursive query with two joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query in which I receive the customer's name, shipped date, order date, and the amount of days that were late. It should only display all of that if the days late is greater than 10 days. Below is the code that I have so far and the results.

The only problem is, there is only supposed to be one row that should be displayed but it's displaying every customer that there is in the database. It seems like a simple fix but I can't figure it out.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
Execute:
select Customers.customerName as 'customer name',
shipdate.shippedDate as 'ship date',
shipdate.orderDate as 'order date',
datediff (shipdate.shippedDate, shipdate.orderDate) as 'days late'

from Customers join Orders 
on Customers.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber


join Orders as shipdate join Orders as orderday 
on shipdate.shippedDate = orderday.shippedDate
where datediff (shipdate.shippedDate, shipdate.orderDate) > 10

    + ------------------ + -------------- + --------------- + -------------- +
| customer name      | ship date      | order date      | days late      |
+ ------------------ + -------------- + --------------- + -------------- +
| Online Diecast Creations Co. | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Blauer See Auto, Co. | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Vitachrome Inc.    | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Baane Mini Imports | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Euro+ Shopping Channel | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Danish Wholesale Imports | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Rovelli Gifts      | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Land of Toys Inc.  | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
| Cruz & Sons Co.    | 2003-12-26 00:00:00 | 2003-10-22 00:00:00 | 65             |
```

Comment: you should copy your sql here

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyp6B.png) @hiule

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code or SQL are useless. This [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) has a list of the many reasons why. SQL and code are both written in plain text, which means they can be directly copied, pasted, and properly formatted in your post. While you're making that [edit], you can also improve your title; it should describe the problem or question in a way that will have meaning to future users here who see it in a list of search results. It's clear you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here, and *stuck for two hours* is meaningless.

Comment: @Rugh You should show your sql directly without image

Comment: Please paste a copy of your code here. Also, the title "SQL help, stuck for two hours" does not describe your problem. Create a more accurate title. With that said, why do you have three JOIN statements but only two ON statements?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will do my best to be clearer next time. Frustration can force myself to improper form. However, I posted an image because text form was very messy and hard to read because of all the results that it displayed.

Comment: @kojow7 Yes, three joins but two on statements. I'm new to SQL and I was trying to run a recursive.

Comment: @Rugh, let's edit your post. Then everyone will vote up your post again. At first time I posted, I was the same as you, as well

Comment: @KenWhite Gotcha. Still trying to fix. Sorry about that.

Comment: @hiule Thank you for the positive effort to help others. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: @Rugh Have you tried Usagi Miyamoto's answer yet? If so, has it worked for you or are you still having problems? If it doesn't work for you post that as a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should try something like this:

```
SELECT Customers.customerName AS customer_name,
       Orders.shippedDate AS ship_date,
       Orders.orderDate AS order_date,
       DATEDIFF( Orders.shippedDate, Orders.orderDate ) AS days_late
FROM Customers
  JOIN Orders ON Customers.customerNumber = Orders.customerNumber
WHERE DATEDIFF( Orders.shippedDate, Orders.orderDate ) > 10
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Except a minor change on the join statement, "cusomerNumber"

Comment: @Rugh Be sure to accept this as the correct answer. Click the checkmark and upvote as well if you want.

Comment: Corrected the typo...,